# Where is Template Path Hints in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento

Just started playing about with Magento 2.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the "Template Path Hints" option that used to be in System > Configuration > Developer > Debug?

Many thanks!

Comment: http://www.thienphucvx.com/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-in-magento2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Front End:**

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

**For Admin :**

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes

Comment: I have enabled it i am on also enabled developer mode from CLI still not able to view template hints

Comment: Flush the cache and try again